# Processes killed by the Android system: does the on going notifications are removed too?

Tags: android, notifications, kill

My application is using an on going notification. I noticed that when I kill my application via DDMS, the on going notification isn’t cancelled. However, when I’m doing Eclipse → Run, the process is killed *and* the notification is canceled.

What happens when the Android system decides to kill my application? Is the notification canceled or do Android just kill the process without doing any cleanup?

**Edit:**
And if there is some cleanup done, how can I simulate this behaviour in order to test if my application is behaving correctly?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the two.

- In Eclipse, "kill" kills the *JVM thread*, everything is destroyed.
- When the Android OS (or DDMS) decides to kill *an application*, the [`killProcess(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29) method is called on this application, via the [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) (I think).
  Notifications are kept.
  In most situations, you don't need to do cleanup. But you might have to override [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I have come across claims ([How to simulate Android killing my process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365301/how-to-simulate-android-killing-my-process/16678376#16678376)) that DDMS does not kill a process the same way it is killed by the Activity LifeCycle.