# Is there a way in Android to simulate a destroyed/collected android.app.Application (Object) like "don't keep activities" does for Activities?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

The behaviour Im seeing is:

If you use "dont keep activities" the memory of the activity will always be destroyed and it will be recreated from scratch with the data from the `Intent` and `savedBundle`everytime the activity comes back from the background. This helps to test android lifecycle issues.

But what else may happen in reality: if the app is in the background for long the `android.app.Application` object itself will be destroyed/collected while simultaneously keeping the stack information of the activities. Android will then try to recreate the activity  with the data from the `Intent` and `savedBundle`, but also recreates the `android.app.Application` object.

So the question: Is there a way to simulate this behaviour?

*EDIT: later found this also answered here:* [How to simulate Android killing my process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365301/how-to-simulate-android-killing-my-process)

Comment: "the android.app.Application object itself will be destroyed/collected" -- more accurately, your process will be terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is:

Just start your app, navigate to the activity you want to test and press the home button (**important app needs to be in background**). Then either with command line:

```
adb shell am kill your.app.package.name
```

or press `Terminate Application` in Android Studio in the Android Monitor:

[image: Android Studio Screenshot showing Terminate Button]

then restart your app with e.g. the launcher icon and the activity will be recreated with a new application object.