# How to know if Application class was called before Activity launch?

Tags: android, android-activity, process, android-lifecycle

We have `Splash extends Activity` which is the starting activity of our application. We also have `CustomApplication extends Application` class which is invoked when the app process in invoked.

Now we have the following requirement. **Whenever the app/process is launched, call `Utils.doSomeDBWork()` function.**

For this purpose we have put this function call in `onCreate()` of `Splash` and `CustomApplication` classes. The reason that we have put this call inside `CustomApplication` is that our application can be launched via `deeplinks/notifications` in which `Splash` won't be called. **But the problem is that if the app was killed and launched via `Splash`, then the same function will be called twice. One from `CustomApplication` and the other through `Splash`.**

So basically my question is that if the function has already been called from `CustomApplication`, then don't call this function from `Splash`. I can think of doing it by using some static variable or Shared Preferences. But don't think that this is a clean way. Is there any other way to achieve this, like passing some info through `Intents` etc?

Comment: You can use Event Bus for this.

Comment: Why do you call your function from an Activity? Isn't it enough to call it from your Application class only?

Answer (score 3):

> How to know that `Application` class was called before `Activity` launch?

In brief, every time when *Android* "gets a request" to start any of your app component (*Activity*, *Service*, *BroadcastReceiver*) and your app isn't running yet, it forks the `app_process` (a.k.a `zygote`), changes its name to `your.package.name` defined in *AndroidManifest.xml*, initializes an *Application* instance, calls its `onCreate()` method, then instantiates the component requested and calls its lifecycle methods (*Activity*'s `onCreate()`, *Service*'s `onCreate()` or *BroadcastReceiver*'s `onReceive()`).

> For this purpose we have put this function call in `onCreate()` of splash and `CustomApplication` classes.

It's redundant. It's enough to call it only from *Application*'s `onCreate()` which is the earliest "entry point" to an app that is guaranteed to be called before any other component's lifecycle methods. There can be only single instance of `Application` class which lives untill the app process dies.

You can easily test it by logging each of the lifecycle methods. After that you won't have any doubts left.

**EDIT** *w.r.t the OP's comment:*

> If the app process was running and the user back presses and exits, and then launches the app again, then `CustomApplication` class won't be called.

This is only partially true. *CustomApplication*'s `onCreate()` won't be called unless the system kills the app process while it is in background (*[simulate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11365301/3290339) the case by, for example, swiping your app from Recents*).

> But our requirement is that `CustomApplication` class should be invoked in this case.

**It's out of developer's scope. Only the system controls that**.

That being said, *CustomApplication*'s `onCreate()` will be called if *Android* kills the app in background. If it doesn't, a simple way to achieve the requirement is to have a `boolean` flag in *CustomApplication* which would indicate if `Utils.doSomeDBWork()` was called.

Comment: If the app process was running and the user back presses and exits, and then launches the app again, then CustomApplication class won't be called. But our requirement is that CustomApplication class should be invoked in this case. That's why we have put the that in onCreate() method of Splash class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call from only applcation's class onCreate?
when App is launched from deeplinks/notifications or Splash, Applcation will always be created first.

Also you can check from static variable.
like below.

```
class Utils{
    public static boolean doneWork = false; // this static variable will be false when app process is killed.

    public doSomeDBWork(){
          if(!doneWork){
              //alreay done..
              return;
          }
          :
          :
          doneWork = true; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some controls with [ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) on application layer. If using it in splashActivity is a solution for you,track your activities and make call in your callback. I hope it gives an idea.