# Where has the "Terminate Application" button gone in the new logcat (Android Studio Dolphin 2022)

Tags: logcat, android-studio-dolphin

The [current docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#new_formatter) do not mention that this very important button has been removed. I imagine it's to do with the way it's tracking processes differently now. Where is it? Do we have to kill processes ourselves via adb now? Why has it moved? Why is no one talking about this?!

[image]

Comment: Yes, why is no one talking about this?  I use this button all the time.  Sigh.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've made [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249950445), we are also missing this feature. You can upvote the issue if you like or add more details.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why this is not a big issue, I must be doing something very wrong :)

Answer (score 19):

With Android Studio Giraffe if you make a right click over the log in the logcat window you can find a menu "Kill process".
[image]

Comment: yeah this was a welcome addition, now the question is if it can be buried in this context menu no one uses, why can it equally not be put back where it was?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me right direction.

Answer (score 9):

It's strange they forgot to include this feature in new logcat. For now you can switch back to the old logcat and you'll get back the option to "Terminate application"

To disable new logcat:
Go to preferences -> Select Experimental option -> Uncheck Enabled new logcat window

Answer (score 9):

Since Android Studio Flamingo, it can be found in "Device **Explorer**" tab in bottom right.

Then there is "Processes" tab where you have the possibility to force stop process and to kill it.

[image]

EDIT: However, according to [this article](https://dev.to/vtsen/how-to-simulate-process-death-in-android-24df), the behaviour differs from the Terminate button...

Comment: I've left a comment on that article and I think the author might be mistaken. My guess is the "terminate application" button is replaced with the "kill process" button, but you must press the home button first, i.e the app can't be in the foreground. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365301/how-to-simulate-android-killing-my-process/26890214#26890214)

Comment: As far as I verified, I am confirming your guesses, just wanted to point out that this whole topic seems way too neglected and messed up in next Android Studio versions. This "Processes" tab seems very buggy (rarely detects proper Process Name in my case)

Comment: yeah I highly doubt I will willingly use the new logcat until they fix it, this aspect is a bit of a mess and surprisingly few seem to notice / care

Comment: I'm on Giraffe and the "kill process" button on the "Device Explorer" tab does exactly what the one in logcat used to do

Answer (score 0):

If need `Terminate Application` button, based on what [google supporst said](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249950445) you can have it back going `Settings >> Experimental >> (and uncheck)Enable new Logcat tool window`.